# Is there a way to detect if an application's window is not completely covered up by other windows?

Tags: windows, winapi

Given a window's HWND, is there a way to find if the window is 'in view', i.e. not covered up by other windows? (Other than the manual finding rectangular bounds of other windows and calculating the intersection, because there exist windows with nonstandard window bounds due to their transparency e.g. oval-ish windows)

Is there also any windows event that is fired when whether or not the window is covered up changes?

Comment: You could call `WindowFromPoint()` for every one of the window's pixels?

Comment: The desktop compositor makes every app believe it is fully visible so that it can produce effects such as taskbar thumbnails, Alt+Tab, Win+Tab, virtual desktops, Snap Assist, Aero Peek, etc.

Comment: Could this be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)? Why do you need to know if a window is covered up or no? What is your use case? What should happen if the window is coverd up (or not covered up)?

Comment: My question is exactly that, though. I am making an app to monitor app usages, and one of the metrics I want to collect is how long an app window is open, with at least a part of the window visible to the user without other windows blocking it.